# How can I let steam games launch from finder instead of only thorugh exec?

Tags: macos, applications

Games from steam had never worked when opened by double clicking on the app in launchpad or apps folder, but a few months ago it also stopped working when launched from Steam. I thought this problem was only related to this launcher but now i have found another completly unrelated app (docker for desktop) that has the same problems.

Both games from steam and docker can be launched by finding the .exec files in the package and executing it. I have reinstalled both apps, and even reinstalled macOs but the problem is still there.

Other apps still work fine. I can provide any necesary files or file structure if needed.

How can I get the game starts to run directly through finder?